# tf.multinomial outputs number other numbers than range

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, tflearn, openai-gym

I am working with the OpenAI gym environment (using policy gradient). My network is outputting an action which is higher than the possible action range.

```
n_outputs = 9
learning_rate = 0.01

initializer = tf.variance_scaling_initializer()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 50, 70, 1])
network = tflearn.conv_2d(X, 32, 5, strides=2, activation='relu')
network = tflearn.max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = tflearn.conv_2d(network, 32, 5, strides=2, activation='relu')
network = tflearn.max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = tflearn.fully_connected(network, 256, activation='relu')
hidden = tf.layers.dense(network, 64, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=initializer)
logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden, n_outputs)
outputs = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
action = tf.multinomial(outputs, num_samples=1)
```

It outputs 9, which creates an error in the gym environment.

The [full code](https://gist.github.com/AhmetHamzaEmra/e5c8603de73d3a35eb617b10d754aaa2).

Comment: Can you please add to your post the **exact** error you're getting? (Just copy and past the traceback).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tf.multinomial will sample outside of the range if it encounters **numerical error**, so in other words - you have NaNs in your graph.

Comment: it turn out to be having nan values from the discount reward function normalizations.

Comment: Awesome tip! I had the exact same problem in reward normalization! Sounds like a bug in tf.multinomial? Super confusing behavior.